# Java - Launch4j, Build failure

Tags: java, ant, exe, launch4j, antbuilder

I am trying to create an executable file from my project but unfortunately I have this failure:

```
 Buildfile: C:\02_DEV\R_5_2_3\DiagraDB\build.xml
    compile:
        [javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\02_DEV\R_5_2_3\DiagraDB\bin
    dist:
          [jar] Building jar: C:\DiagraDB_build\lib\DiagraDB.jar
         [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\DiagraDB_build\mysql
     [launch4j] Compiling resources
     [launch4j] Linking
     [launch4j] C:\02_DEV\R_5_2_3\DiagraDB\launch4j\bin\ld.exe: C:\02_DEV\R_5_2_3\DiagraDB\launch4j\w32api\crt2.o: No such file: No such file or directory

    BUILD FAILED
    C:\02_DEV\R_5_2_3\DiagraDB\build.xml:125: net.sf.launch4j.BuilderException: net.sf.launch4j.ExecException: Exec failed (1): C:\02_DEV\R_5_2_3\DiagraDB\launch4j\bin\ld.exe -mi386pe --oformat pei-i386 --subsystem windows -s C:\02_DEV\R_5_2_3\DiagraDB\launch4j\w32api\crt2.o C:\02_DEV\R_5_2_3\DiagraDB\launch4j\head\guihead.o C:\02_DEV\R_5_2_3\DiagraDB\launch4j\head\head.o C:\Users\MET4ABT\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j5622103051739315213o C:\02_DEV\R_5_2_3\DiagraDB\launch4j\w32api\libmingw32.a C:\02_DEV\R_5_2_3\DiagraDB\launch4j\w32api\libgcc.a C:\02_DEV\R_5_2_3\DiagraDB\launch4j\w32api\libmsvcrt.a C:\02_DEV\R_5_2_3\DiagraDB\launch4j\w32api\libkernel32.a C:\02_DEV\R_5_2_3\DiagraDB\launch4j\w32api\libuser32.a C:\02_DEV\R_5_2_3\DiagraDB\launch4j\w32api\libadvapi32.a C:\02_DEV\R_5_2_3\DiagraDB\launch4j\w32api\libshell32.a -o C:\DiagraDB_build\DiagraDB.exe

    Total time: 6 seconds
```

I have read some kind of stuff such as [Launch4j / windres: how to set paths correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319358/launch4j-windres-how-to-set-paths-correctly)  but I couldn't make it work for mine.
(I have the JDK Version 7 and windows 7.) I appreciate your suggestions about a solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: set JAVA_HOME then restart cmd

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb already tried but it's not working :/